# Hooking in Immunity - LogBpHook not working

Tags: debugging, immunity-debugger, function-hooking

I try to use a simple hook on different memory allocation functions in Immunity. But the hook doesn't react at all (no logging).

First of all my hook class:

```
class AllocHook(LogBpHook):
    def __init__(self):
        LogBpHook.__init__(self)

    def run(self, regs):
        imm = immlib.Debugger()
        imm.log("     ++++++++++++++++++ HOOOKED")
        imm.log(str(regs))
        imm.log("     ++++++++++++++++++ HOOOKED")
```

The function to init and add the hook.

```
def hookAlloc(imm):
    global vAllocHo
    # Retrieve address of Allocs
    # Create hook object and add hook
    va1 = imm.getAddress("kernel32.LocalAlloc")
    vAllocHo = AllocHook()
    vAllocHo.add("va alloc",va1)
    vAllocHo.enable()
```

So the `log` appears in the breakpoint window, but the `run()` function actually never gets called.

```
Breakpoints, item 26
Address=76C91668 kernel32.LocalAlloc
Module=kernel32
Active=Log
Disassembly=MOV EDI,EDI
```

The log messages of the breakpoints are at least disappearing when the hook is activated. For example, after activating the hook, the following logging messages are not displayed anymore:

```
Log data, item 40
Address=76C91668 
Message=[19:12:51] Breakpoint at kernel32.LocalAlloc
```

Are there special settings in the options left, which I have to consider first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the heat of the moment I didn't start Immunity as an Administrator.
So missing privileges have caused this behaviour during the debugging process.